# Использование фонового изображения рабочего стола Windows как фон для программы на C#

Tags: winforms

Нужно использовать фоновую картинку рабочего стола в качестве фона приложения. Есть идеи как это реализовать? Или проще скрыть все ярлыки с рабочего стола и сделать программе прозрачный фон?

Comment: Делать скрин фонового изображения без ярлыков и открытых программ и ставить его на фон твоей программы. Делал так на Delphi, уверен, что на c# тоже есть способ.

Answer (score 0):

Самый простой вариант это сделать прозрачным вашу основную форму.
Если прям хотите подтянуть картинку, то нужно из реестра подтянуть путь картинки и потом указать ее как фоновую у вашей формы.

[Ссылка](https://www.videosharp.info/webinar/answers/id=229) на немного другой пример